# FileField is valid even when empty

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a parent and child model:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.SlugField(max_length=45, null=False)
    tags = TaggableManager()


class Child(models.Model):
    version = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=10, default='1.0')
    upload = models.FileField(
        upload_to=hack_upload_path,
        blank=False,
        null=False
    )

    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        Parent,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='versions'
    )

    class Meta:
        get_latest_by = "upload_date"
        verbose_name = "version"
        verbose_name_plural = "versions"

    def __str__(self):
        return f'v{self.version}'
```

A parent basically has multiple children which are just file uploads with some more data.
So I have a form where I want to create a Parent and one Child at the same time, so I made this form and view:

```
class ParentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        fields = [
            'name',
            'tags'
        ]



ChildFormset = inlineformset_factory(
    Parent,
    Child,
    fields=(
        'version',
        'upload'
    ),
    extra=1,
    max_num=1,
    can_delete=False,
)

class ParentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = ParentForm
    template_name = 'new.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['versions'] = ChildFormset(
                self.request.POST,
                self.request.FILES,
                instance=self.object
            )
        else:
            data['versions'] = ChildFormset(instance=self.object)
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.seller = self.request.user
        context = self.get_context_data()
        versions = context['versions']
        if versions.is_valid():
            # It comes here even though the upload field is empty!
            self.object = form.save()
            versions.instance = self.object
            versions.save()
            return super().form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.render_to_response(
                self.get_context_data(
                    form=form,
                    versions=versions
                )
            )
```

And It passes the `if versions.is_valid():` check even though the file upload field is empty.

Any ideas why it doesn't validate the inline form correctly (the version field gets validated good but the file upload field not)?

this is the template:

```
                <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <fieldset class="form-group">
                        {{ form|crispy }}
                        {{ versions|crispy }}
                    </fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Upload</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: it seems that if I enter a new 'version' in the version field i do get normal validation, it seems like the version gets updated and not created with the parent model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by setting `min_num=1` in the formsetfactory